# Is there a way to enable "native method prefix" capabilities in a java language (non-native) JVM agent?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, jvmti

background:  java has a mechanism for instrumenting native methods by basically allowing you to rename the native method with a set prefix and then create a method that delegates to it, in bytecode.

It appears by default this is disallowed.  Calling `Instrumentation.setNativePrefix()` performs a check on `InstrumentationImpl.mEnvironmentSupportsNativeMethodPrefix`, which I see in the jvm C code defaults to "false".

I see there is possibly a way to enable it with a native agent via JVMTI, but I can't find anything about enabling it with a java-language agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required capabilities for a Java Agent are determined by the Manifest Attributes of its jar file, as specified at [the bottom of the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html#navbar.bottom):

> #### Manifest Attributes
>
> The following manifest attributes are defined for an agent JAR file:
>
> …
>
> - Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix
>     Boolean (`true` or `false`, case irrelevant). Is the ability to set native method prefix needed by this agent. Values other than `true` are considered `false`. This attribute is optional, the default is `false`.

I didn’t try it specifically with the native method prefix, but I know from the other capabilities (redefinition and retransformation) that they are only reported as supported by the `Instrumentation` interface when previously requested via the manifest attributes. The absence of any startup-time agent requesting the feature may even make it impossible to request the feature later-on by an agent loaded via the Attach API.